# Django setting a transaction for class-based redirect view

Tags: python, django, transactions

I have the following class-based view with simple likes-toggling mechanics:

class PostLikeToggle(RedirectView):

```
def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    post_id = kwargs.get('pk')
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    user = self.request.user
    if post.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(user)
    else:
        post.likes.add(user)
    url_redirect = post.get_absolute_url(post_id)
    return url_redirect
```

I think of making this method as an atomic transaction, but not sure about the proper way to do that.
Am I on the right track?

```
class PostLikeToggle(RedirectView):
    @transaction.atomic
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it, first is what you said:

```
class PostLikeToggle(RedirectView):
    @transaction.atomic
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

Second option:

```
def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs)
    try: 
        with transaction.atomic(): 
            pass  # CRUD operations 
    except IntegrityError: 
        handle_exception()  # this will run after rollback
```